# Vectorized insertion of elements

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

I wrote a `R` function `insert` to insert a given element `e` at a given position `p` of a vector `v`.

Here it is:

```
insert <- function(v, e, p) {
  if (length(e) != 1 || length(p) != 1) {
    stop('supported the insertion of only one element per call.')
  }
  len <- length(v)
  nms <- names(v)
  enm <- names(e)
  res <- NULL
  if (p > 1 && p <= len) {
    res <- c(v[1:(p-1)], e, v[p:len]) # insert
  } else if (p == 1) {
    res <- c(e, v) # prepend 
  } else if (p == (len+1)) {
    res <- c(v, e) # append
  } else {
    stop('wrong position')
  }
  if (!is.null(enm)) {
      names(res) <- insert(nms, enm, p)
  }
  res
}
```

Note that this function, like almost everything in R, returns a new vector. In addition (see recursive call), it **inserts also the name of the element**, if it has one.

Here is a simple example of use:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10)
names(a) <- c(letters[1:5], letters[7:8], letters[10])
a
# a  b  c  d  e  g  h  j 
# 1  2  3  4  5  7  8 10  
b <- c(9)
names(b) <- letters[9]
insert(a, b, 8)
# a  b  c  d  e  g  h  i  j 
# 1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10
```

I'm trying to write a **vectorized (and efficient) version** of this function.

For now, I wrote a little elegant **solution**:

```
vinsert <- function(v, elems, positions) {
  out <- v
  for (i in 1:length(elems)) {
    out <- insert(out, elems[i], positions[i])
  }
  out
}
```

And here a simple example of use:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10)
names(a) <- c(letters[1:5], letters[7:8], letters[10])
a
# a  b  c  d  e  g  h  j 
# 1  2  3  4  5  7  8 10
z <- c(6,9)
names(z) <- c(letters[6], letters[9])
z
# f  i
# 6  9
vinsert(a, z, z)
# a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j 
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

So, the issues that I am considering about both functions (`insert` and `vinsert`) are:

1. return a new vector or modify the vector in place and return it?
2. write an equivalent function with `Rcpp`?
3. it is possible to write an equivalent function using first order `R` function?

Any suggest, help or more elegant and efficient solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an unvectorized `base` function `append` that appears to do what you want `insert` to do.

Comment: @mnel: you are right, thanks. `append` is equivalent to my `insert` function. still remains the problem of a vectorized and efficient solution to insert more elements in different position.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to modify in place unless the vector is overallocated, otherwise you will not be returning the full length vector (or perhaps I'm not understanding what you mean by point 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like there are a number of issues, e.g., how the order of insertion is influenced by prior insertions, and what to do when inserting sequences of more than one element. Here we have an original sequence

```
x <- letters[1:10]
```

and some things we'd like to insert into it

```
v <- LETTERS[1:4]
```

and where we'd like to insert them

```
at <- c(4, 7, 2, 6)
```

One way of doing the insertion is to figure out the order of the new index values `at` relative to the original; `order` is providing a *stable* order

```
o <- order(c(seq_along(x), at))
```

and then to do the insertion

```
> c(x, v)[o]
 [1] "a" "b" "C" "c" "d" "A" "e" "f" "D" "g" "B" "h" "i" "j"
```

The insertion rules are not quite the same as your original

```
> o = order(c(seq_along(a), z))
> c(a, z)[o]
 a  b  c  d  e  g  f  h  j  i 
 1  2  3  4  5  7  6  8 10  9
```

Comment: +1 especially for the stable ordering bit. My solution extends this to allow varying length elements of the values to insert.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that allows for multiple values for `after` (requiring values to be  a list of the same length

```
vappend <- function(x, values, after){
  lx <- length(x)
  if(missing(after)){
    after <- length(x)
  }
  la <- length(after)
  if(la ==1L){
    return(append(x, unlist(values), after))
  } else {
    stopifnot(length(values) == length(after))
    lv <- sapply(values, length)

    aae <- rep.int(after,lv) 
    c(x, unlist(values))[order(c(seq_along(x), aae))]

  }
}


vappend(x = 1:5, values = list(2:3,3:5),after = 1:2)
## [1] 1 2 3 2 3 4 5 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you are just appending at "position" determined by value and not index. In that case you just have to use `c` and `order`.

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10)
names(a) <- letters[a]
a
##  a  b  c  d  e  g  h  j 
##  1  2  3  4  5  7  8 10 


z <- c(6, 9)
names(z) <- letters[z]
z
## f i 
## 6 9 


result <- c(a, z)[order(c(a, z))]
result
##  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j 
##  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```